# Blank response after uploading Symfony2 project on CPanel hosting

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, cpanel

I deployed my Symfony2 project to CPanel hosting via ftp, change web directory to public_html and follow [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html) tutorial and some others. But when I go to home page I receive blank response with status 200.

I tried to add `var_dump(Request::createFromGlobals());` in `app.php` to be sure that request builds correctly and it does. And then line `$response = $kernel->handle($request);` returns nothing. I also tried to give 777 rights to project folders.

It must be something simple and obvious but I'm so newbe in PHP and Symfony so forgive me please.

P.S. configuration checker on `/config.php` returns no error, just few suggesions about php accelerator, switch off short_open_tag and intl extension.

Comment: Check symfony logs for more detailed information.

Comment: I tried, but there are no logs. And I gave all rights on logs folder.

Comment: Did you warm cache after uploading your project? Do you have ssh access to your hosting?

Comment: Actually I have only ftp access. Is warming cache necessary? I change .htaccess to use app_dev.php instead of app.php

Comment: Default, app_dev.php have restrictions to access outside of localhost (you can modify it, but i don't recommend this to do on production), but some hosting providers allow to configure ssh access via control panels, may be yours allow this too.

Comment: I removed localhost restrictions since I don't want to use this project in real production. I just need to access it on internet. I'll try to get ssh access but it might be not possible because I don't have any rights there.